# 20.04 Bluetooth not working

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

My bluetooth doesn't work. When I try to scan, it says:

```
Failed to start discovery: org.bluez.Error.NotReady
```

The output of `systemctl status bluetooth.service` is

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-12-21 13:53:02 CST; 15min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 27897 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18637)
     Memory: 1.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─27897 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dec 21 13:53:02 di-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[27897]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Dec 21 13:53:02 di-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[27897]: Starting SDP server
Dec 21 13:53:02 di-XPS-15-9560 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Dec 21 13:53:02 di-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[27897]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Dec 21 13:53:02 di-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[27897]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
Dec 21 13:53:02 di-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[27897]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.474 path=/MediaEndp>
Dec 21 13:53:02 di-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[27897]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.474 path=/MediaEndp>
Dec 21 13:53:02 di-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[27897]: Failed to set mode: Blocked through rfkill (0x12)
Dec 21 13:53:13 di-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[27897]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
Dec 21 13:59:15 di-XPS-15-9560 bluetoothd[27897]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
```

But the output of `rfkill` is

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
```

Reboot can fix the issue, but it may occur again.

Edit:

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a56:1535]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
```

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cf3:e301 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2b95 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`dmesg | grep -i blue`

```
[    2.270306] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.270320] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.270322] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.270324] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.270326] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.873627] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.873628] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.873632] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 1002.965436] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 1002.965442] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 1002.965447] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[26300.160820] Bluetooth: hci0: advertising data len corrected
[85513.688930] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout
[85513.688932] Bluetooth: hci0: failed to disable LE scan: status 0x1f
[86460.467488] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0804 tx timeout
[86490.707335] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0402 tx timeout
[86492.723330] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout
[86566.674885] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c1a tx timeout
[86568.694839] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0402 tx timeout
[86569.718448] bluetoothd[712]: segfault at 30 ip 00005618835516ba sp 00007ffc4ab08a70 error 4 in bluetoothd[5618834ef000+9b000]
[86572.299042] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 0000000043e6a2ef failed to resubmit (113)
[86582.506969] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000004a0fbd04 failed to resubmit (113)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: This looks like a but to me. You can report it by `ubuntu-bug linux`. But you will be asked to test mainline kernels.